# Use dateadd returns working day

Tags: sql, dateadd

I am using the below to calculate the next date but this could return a non working day.

```
dateadd(day, 365, nullif(last_service, '01/01/1900')) as [next_service]
```

For example `last_service` is `07.03.2014` then the `next_service` would be `07.03.2015` which is a Saturday.

How to do avoid this so only working day is returned?

Thanks for your help and guidance on this.

Comment: So in that example what should be the result.

Comment: Start by creating a calendar table with the working days for your environment.

Comment: I would like it to return the next working day

Answer (score 6):

I suggest building a calendar table.  Next working day will not be the same for everyone due to varying holidays and other policies, joining to a calendar table is quick and clean.  There are many resources to help create your calendar table, here is one:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/

Usage could vary:

```
SELECT a.*,b.NextBusinessDay AS next_service
FROM YourTable a
JOIN tlkp_Calendar b
 ON DATEADD(year,1,a.last_service) = b.CalendarDate
```

Or if you bake the extra year into your calendar table:

```
SELECT a.*,b.Next_Service 
FROM YourTable a
JOIN tlkp_Calendar b
 ON a.last_service = b.CalendarDate
```

Comment: This still returns the same date when using the calendar.

Comment: @user3452212 You'll need to build the next business day, or the next service date into your calendar table to make this work, but in either query the field you select should have a different date.